# Entity Framework Model Multiple Table to Single Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-modeling

I've two tables named Modules and Privileges which are related by a foreign key relationship as shown below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [baburajpb at sites.google.com](https://sites.google.com/site/baburajpb/model.png))</sub>

I'd like to model Module and Privilege by adding ModuleName to Privilege. Later I'd be interested in creating a derived class (Menu in the illustration) from Privilege by adding a discriminating condition on ModuleName. Is this possible using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you map multiple tables to a single entity type? [Sure, that is supported.](http://blogs.msdn.com/bags/archive/2009/03/09/entity-framework-modeling-entity-splitting.aspx) However, you cannot use a mapped field of the table (ModuleName) as a discriminator column for table per hierarchy mapping. The discriminator column must be used as a discriminator alone, and must not be mapped into your client schema.